# Saving objects of different subclasses in one collection

Tags: java, collections, polymorphism, filewriter

Devs,

I have a beginner questions for a assignment. I need to safe to different subclasses from my superclass in a collection and save the output in a file.
So I created a ContainerClass and initialized my collection for my superclass like this:

````
```Collection <Kreditvertrag> Kreditvertraege = null;``
````

in a method below I am iterating through the collection and saving the values of "Kreditvertrag" to a text file.

```
for (Kreditvertrag kr : this.Kreditvertraege) {

            vfile.write(String.valueOf(kr.varInKreditbetrag));

        }
```

Here I want to write variables from 2 different subclasses of "Kreditvertrag" to the "Kreditvertraege" collection.

Can someone lead me in the right direction ?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can´t access the variables from my subclass in the for loop.

Comment: you can’t “write variables into the collection”. You can add objects to the collection. Since your loop doesn’t add objects to the collection, but writes already contained objects to a file, it’s not clear what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use a list:

```
ArrayList<Kreditvertrag> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(subOject1);
list.add(subOject2);
for (Kreditvertrag kr : list) {
        vfile.write(String.valueOf(kr.varInKreditbetrag));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same behavior for your 2 subclasses, there is no need to cast them to their subclass. If you want different behavior, you can work with "method overloading" (clean) or "instance of" (not so clean)